# How to display result of 'oninput' calculation in a different textbox? (HTML)

Tags: forms, html

I have a couple of text boxes that accept numeric values. When a user enters a value in one of them it should run a calculation and display it in the other textbox (& vice versa). I've been playing around with the code and have got this, however it doesn't seem to display the value.

```
<form oninput="valueB.value=valueA.value+900">
    <input type="number" name="valueA" value="" />
</form>

<form oninput="valueA.value=valueB.value+300">
    <input type="number" name="valueB" value="" />
</form>
```

I notice that there is the `<output>` tag that can be used to display results, however I don't see how I'd make use of this to display the value in the text box. Please can someone offer some advice on what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements should not have global references pointing to them via their `name` attribute.  If you change the `name` attribute to `id`, you will see that it almost works as expected, you just need to cast the value to a number before performing the addition.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/nvQLb/**

---

As a general rule, you should keep your JavaScript and HTML separate, and refer to elements in the document using a *fetching* method like `document.getElementsByName` or `document.querySelector`.  That way, your code is easier to maintain and you will avoid any ambiguities that may arise by variables having the same name as a DOM element's `id`.